# Correspondance of codemirror modes, file extensions, and github flavored markdown code languages?

Tags: file-extension, codemirror, github-flavored-markdown

I'd like to embed local files as code snippets in a **static** website I'm making with jade, marked and codemirror for syntax highlighing. I will write a jade filter to do this.

What it boils down to is that I need to come up with the codemirror mode and github flavored markdown language (what you write when you do ```language) from the file extension.

At least some codemirror modes correspond to gfm languages. Do all of them coincide?
Is there a list somewhere, or some rationale for the names?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mode/meta.js` file in CodeMirror's distribution associates names with modes (via the `CodeMirror.findModeByName` function), and if you get CodeMirror version 4.8 (released yesterday), the `gfm` mode will use this list to try and use the right mode for fenced code blocks that declare a language.

Answer (score 2):

[This list](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/language/languages.json) from the Brackets matches file extension with cm mode. I've turned it into this:

```
{"groovy": "groovy",
"ini": "properties",
"properties": "properties",
"css": "css",
"scss": "css",
"html": "htmlmixed",
"htm": "htmlmixed",
"shtm": "htmlmixed",
"shtml": "htmlmixed",
"xhtml": "htmlmixed",
"cfm": "htmlmixed",
"cfml": "htmlmixed",
"cfc": "htmlmixed",
"dhtml": "htmlmixed",
"xht": "htmlmixed",
"tpl": "htmlmixed",
"twig": "htmlmixed",
"hbs": "htmlmixed",
"handlebars": "htmlmixed",
"kit": "htmlmixed",
"jsp": "htmlmixed",
"aspx": "htmlmixed",
"ascx": "htmlmixed",
"asp": "htmlmixed",
"master": "htmlmixed",
"cshtml": "htmlmixed",
"vbhtml": "htmlmixed",
"ejs": "htmlembedded",
"dust": "htmlembedded",
"erb": "htmlembedded",
"js": "javascript",
"jsx": "javascript",
"jsm": "javascript",
"_js": "javascript",
"vbs": "vbscript",
"vb": "vb",
"json": "javascript",
"xml": "xml",
"svg": "xml",
"wxs": "xml",
"wxl": "xml",
"wsdl": "xml",
"rss": "xml",
"atom": "xml",
"rdf": "xml",
"xslt": "xml",
"xsl": "xml",
"xul": "xml",
"xbl": "xml",
"mathml": "xml",
"config": "xml",
"plist": "xml",
"xaml": "xml",
"php": "php",
"php3": "php",
"php4": "php",
"php5": "php",
"phtm": "php",
"phtml": "php",
"ctp": "php",
"c": "clike",
"h": "clike",
"i": "clike",
"cc": "clike",
"cp": "clike",
"cpp": "clike",
"c++": "clike",
"cxx": "clike",
"hh": "clike",
"hpp": "clike",
"hxx": "clike",
"h++": "clike",
"ii": "clike",
"ino": "clike",
"cs": "clike",
"asax": "clike",
"ashx": "clike",
"java": "clike",
"scala": "clike",
"sbt": "clike",
"coffee": "coffeescript",
"cf": "coffeescript",
"cson": "coffeescript",
"_coffee": "coffeescript",
"clj": "clojure",
"cljs": "clojure",
"cljx": "clojure",
"pl": "perl",
"pm": "perl",
"rb": "ruby",
"ru": "ruby",
"gemspec": "ruby",
"rake": "ruby",
"py": "python",
"pyw": "python",
"wsgi": "python",
"sass": "sass",
"lua": "lua",
"sql": "sql",
"diff": "diff",
"patch": "diff",
"md": "markdown",
"markdown": "markdown",
"mdown": "markdown",
"mkdn": "markdown",
"yaml": "yaml",
"yml": "yaml",
"hx": "haxe",
"sh": "shell",
"command": "shell",
"bash": "shell"}
```